# Determining if the Replied Message Contains an exception in .Net Remoting Channel IMessageSink

Tags: .net, exception, remoting, channel

I am working on a .Net Remoting project. and I want to monitor the remote calls and returned values or possible exceptions.
I Implemented the IMessageSink

```
    Public Function SyncProcessMessage(ByVal msg As System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage) As System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage Implements System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink.SyncProcessMessage

        Dim replyMsg As IMessage = _NextMessageSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg)

        if {ReplyMsg Contains Exception of type a} then 
            do something
        else if {ReplyMsg Contains Exception of type b} then 
            do someshing else
        End If

        Return replyMsg
    End Function
```

when the service throws an exception ReplyMsg only contains the LogicalCallContext.
how can i find the exception types?

Comment: BTW, I hope you're aware that Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF?

Comment: yes, But this is a huge system and implemented years ago,and we cannot move to WCF right now, I'm only Changing ChannelSinks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what type your _NextMessageSink is, but if I look at BinaryClientFormatterSink it will wrap any exception within a ReturnMessage. ReturnMessage implements IMethodReturnMessage that provides an Exception property. So it's possible the following may work:

```
IMethodReturnMessage returnMessage = replyMsg as IMethodReturnMessage;
if (returnMessage != null)
{
    Exception exception = returnMessage.Exception;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as the following code is my case. you have to unbox "replyMsg" to check exception or not.

```
ReturnMessage replyMsgEntity = replyMsg as ReturnMessage;
if(replyMsgEntity != null && replyMsgEntity.Exception != null)
{
    //# TRACE-EXCEPTION....
}
```